# VB newline escape char?

Tags: c++, c, vb.net, newline, output

In C I use `"1st line 1\n2nd line"` for a newline, but what about VB? I know `"1st line" & VbCrLf & "2nd line"` but its too verbose, what is the escape char for a newline in VB?

I want to print

```
1st line
2nd line
```

I tried using `\n` but it always outputs this no matter how many times I run the compiler

```
1st line\n2nd line
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can also use `myStr = myStr.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)` where myStr already contain your content incl. \n. Works well as a custom extension too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `Environment.NewLine`. That evaluates to CR+LF on Windows, and LF on Unix systems.

There are no escape sequences for CR or LF characters in VB. And that's why `"\n"` is treated literally. So, `Environment.NewLine` is your guy.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you should be using the environment-sensitive `Environment.NewLine` property.  `vbCrLf` is an old VB6 constant which is provided in VB.NET for backwards compatability.  So for instance, you should be using:

```
"1st line" & Environment.NewLine & "2nd line"
```

If that's too wordy when you have many lines, you can use the `StringBuilder` class, instead:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
builder.AppendLine("line 1")
builder.AppendLine("line 2")
builder.AppendLine("line 3")
builder.AppendLine("line 4")
```

If you specifically need the CR and LF characters, you should be using the constants in the `ControlChars` class instead of the old `vbCrLf` constant.

Answer (score 2):

You say VB, but have tagged with VB.NET. Your question is slightly odd as well. Different OSes actually require different newline characters. What you want is `Environment.NewLine`. This will give you the correct new line character(s) no matter what OS the .NET framework is running on.

Answer (score 2):

I still using the old fashioned `chr(13)`
for example:

```
"Hello" & chr(13) & "World"
```

It results in:

```
Hello
World
```

EDIT: Like ***Dave Doknjas*** said, in your case it would be `chr(10)` to feed the line.

Comment: If you're going to use Chr, then use Chr(10) - that's the equivalent to "\n" (which is the original question).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an inline escape to accomplish something like including line breaks in a String.Format you can include a pipe or something similar and then replace it at the end of your string.

> String.Format("Batch: {0} | ProductNumber: {1} | Formula: {2}", dr.Item("BatchNumber"), dr.Item("PartNum"), dr.Item("Formula")).Replace("|", Environment.NewLine)