# newline not showing after calling JSON Restful web services

Tags: objective-c, json, vb.net, newline

I have missing newline \n in a string after receiving it from iOS app through JSON post restful API. I have a string with a newline in iOS "the weather is \n fine" but after calling API i am receiving it without \n on the (vb.net). 
I want to see the newline character \n so i can split it in 2 phrases.

Code:

```
self.dataRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.dataRequest setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self.dataRequest setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self.dataRequest setPostBody:(NSMutableData *)[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[self.dataRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[self.dataRequest setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[self.dataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self.dataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076179/vb-newline-escape-char

Comment: Sadly Environment.NewLine is not detected in the string the VB using indexof or contains

Comment: Shouldn't you be searching for "\n"? Environment.NewLine is what to use on the VB side instead of \n